# F# Equivalent of Destructor

Tags: f#, finalizer, c#-to-f#

I am translating a C# class that wraps an unmanaged library to F#. I have run into the seemingly simple problem of rewriting the destructor that follows.

```
class Wrapper {

    // P/Invoke ellided

    private SomeType x;

    public Wrapper() {
        x = new SomeType();
        Begin();
    }

    public ~Wrapper() {
        End();
    }
```

The simplified F# code I have at this point is as follows:

```
type Wrapper() =
  [<Literal>]
  static let wrappedDll = "Library.dll"

  [<DllImport(wrappedDll , EntryPoint = "Begin")>]
  static extern void Begin()

  [<DllImport(wrappedDll , EntryPoint = "End")>]
  static extern void End()

  let x = new SomeType()

  do
    Begin()
```

How can I modify this F# code to have the same behaviour? My search for F# destructor turned up no results in the books I have or on the web.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to implement IDisposable interface in your class that aggregates unmanaged resources?

Comment: You have a C# class that has a finalizer but doesn't implement `IDisposable`? How bizarre

Comment: FYI - here's a blog article on how to implement IDisposable properly: http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/stevehawley/archive/2006/09/21/10887.aspx

Comment: Implementing IDisposable in a thread-safe way may be harder.

Comment: I am learning F# and improving my C# as I make this translation of another persons code. Thank you for the advice on using IDisposable, I have much room to improve and would like to make positive contributions to this code.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you need to implement IDisposable if you aggregate a disposable object, or if you hold on to an unmanaged resource.  Cleanup is done differently for these two scenarios.  Otherwise, keep it simple, don't litter your code with dotnetisms.

Comment: @GregC : Wow, that was an excellent way of wording it.

Comment: @ildjarn : I heard it in school, in a class taught by Venkat Subramaniam.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you tried looking for F# finalizer?

```
override x.Finalize() = ...
```

Answer (score 12):

```cs
namespace FSharp.Library  

type MyClass() as self = 

    let mutable disposed = false;

    // TODO define your variables including disposable objects

    do // TODO perform initialization code
        ()

    // internal method to cleanup resources
    let cleanup(disposing:bool) = 
        if not disposed then
            disposed <- true

            if disposing then
                // TODO dispose of managed resources
                ()

            // TODO cleanup unmanaged resources
            ()

    // implementation of IDisposable
    interface IDisposable with
        member self.Dispose() =
            cleanup(true)
            GC.SuppressFinalize(self)

    // override of finalizer
    override self.Finalize() = 
        cleanup(false)
```

F# Class Library Template

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/06/05/f-class-library-template.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it must be defined the same as C# compiler does

```
override c.Finalize() =
    try
        // do finalization
    finally
        base.Finalize()
```

Because exception in your finalization code can corrupt something.
Otherwise I misunderstand why C# does that.