# In which real life scenario you used garbage collector?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, garbage-collection

I know all the theories :

I know what is GC, when to call dispose, Finalise when it is getting called.

I would like to know, in your live project ..in which scenario have used all this.

- I mean when the project
  manager/client insisted you to
  cleanup the memory ? When you find
  any errors in the programs? Kind of
  error messages or error logs? When
  your program got crashed because of
  unwanted memory? or any other
  scenarios?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all...

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647790.aspx#scalenetchapt05_topic9

Comment: Possibly related http://stackoverflow.com/q/478167/38206

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not care when and how GC is called. It is inteligent enough to know when to run and what objects to free.

You should also Dispose, either manualy or using "using" all objects, that implement IDisposable. You will then prevent many errors with un-managed resources, like files.

And if you are running out of memory, then there is something wrong with your algorithm or code itself. Manualy calling GC.Collect is heavily discuraged, especialy in production code.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, you need to implement IDisposable if you aggregate a disposable object, or if you hold on to an unmanaged resource. Cleanup is done differently for these two scenarios. Otherwise, keep it simple, don't litter your code with dotnetisms

[Similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676791/f-equivalent-of-destructor/5676860#5676860)

Memory leaks cause crashed up servers.  Cause and effect.

Comment: So you are saying that in your project you implemented this by default..not any one insisted or never you got a program crash ..right?

Comment: We actually ran out of memory space on a 32-bit process before being stickler about it, but it's a big unknown.  YMMV

Answer (score 1):

Ressource management is something you just havce to do. It is not 'my client insisted I free my memory'. It is simply good practice. Not all applications may crash and the user just restarts them - there is one or other server application out there.

If you start building your programming libraries, ressource management and concurrency should be your top priority, otherwise you will never be up to speed implementing any solution.

hth

Mario